# -webkit does not have any effect on the view

Tags: html, css, safari

```
.img-responsive{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5%;
    -webkit-height:25% !important;
    max-height: 25vh;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;

}
```

Why doesn't the webkit have any effect on how the image is represented?

Answer (score 1):

Please correct `max-height: 25vh;` by `max-height: 25px;` might be your browser doesn't support Viewport units vh. -webkit only support in chrome and Safari.

Comment: It works in chrome fine, in safari it just doesn't apply.